# Unity, fresnel shader on raw image

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, shader

Hello I'm trying to archive the effect in the image below (that is like shine light but only on top of the raw image)
Unfortunately I can not figure out how to do it, tried some shaders and assets from the asset store, but so far no one has worked, also I dont know much about shaders.

The raw image is an ui element, and renders a render texture that is being captured by a camera.

I'm totally lost here, any kind of help will be appreciated, how to make that effect?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Is this not just a standard edge highlight? Perhaps modified as an alpha-edge highlight?

Answer (score 2):

Fresnel shaders use the difference between the surface normal and the view vector to detect which pixels are facing the viewer and which aren't. A UI plane will always face the user, so no luck there.

Solving this with shaders can be done in two ways - either you bake a normal map of the imagined "curvature" of the outer edge ([example](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/7/0/c/70cb78566136aafeaa8e4dd5c6db8b4eef032baf.jpg)), or you create a signed distance field ([example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dfcreative/bitmap-sdf/master/preview.png)), or some similar method which maps the distance to the edge. A normal map would probably allow for the most complex effects, and i am sure that some fresnel shaders could work with that too. It does however require you to make a model of the shape and bake the normals from that.

A signed distance field on the other hand can be generated with script from an image, so if you have a lot of images, it might be the fastest approach. Getting the edge distance in real time inside the shader would not really work since you'd have to sample a very large amount of neighboring pixels, which might make the shader 10-20 times slower depending on how thick you need the edge to be.

If you don't need the image to be that dynamic, then maybe just creating an inner glow black/white texture in Photoshop and overlaying it using an additive shader would work better for you. If you don't know how to write shaders, then maybe the two above approaches are a bit of a tall order.

Comment: If the outline of the sprite is coming from an alpha channel (as opposed to just being the quad's border), then you could also just try to compute those on the fly, sampling lower mips etc. It might not look as nice, but tbh a sdf based solution will not have that nice "gaussian blur" aspect either, it will actually look like the "precise" mode of inner glows in Photoshop.

Comment: Sampling a lower mip level is not a bad idea, perhaps combining that with averaging between nearby samples/gaussian blur might work.